# How to pass values into URL's from csv

Tags: locust

DC = Delegate_Code.pop()
        print(DC)
        with self.client.get("/api/StatusInfo/Get?DelegateCode=KY001"

I want to pass the var 'DC' into the URL (KY001). How is this done? Things I've tried haven't worked.

DC = Delegate_Code.pop()
        print(DC)
        with self.client.get("/api/StatusInfo/Get?DelegateCode=(DC)"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in lots of ways (basically any way that python supports)

For example (python 3.6+)

self.client.get(f"/api/StatusInfo/Get?DelegateCode={DC}")

Older:

self.client.get("/api/StatusInfo/Get?DelegateCode=" + DC)

You can also have a look at the csv reader I made specifically for locust (part of locust-plugins). Here's an example of how to use it: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/csvreader.py